# How to prove that the range of this integral operator $T$ is $L^2[a,b]$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, inner-products, integral-operators

The operator is $Tf= g(t)+ \int_{a}^{t}(K(t,s)f(s)ds.$
The proof assumes that $g(t) \in L^2[a,b]$ so I believe I need to only prove that $\int_{a}^{t}(K(t,s)f(s)ds \in L^2[a,b]$.

I started off this way:

$$\|Tf\|^2=\int_{a}^{b}|\int_{a}^{t}(K(t,s)f(s)ds|^2dt$$
However, I'm confused at this point. Can I say by Schwarz inequality,
$$\|Tf\|^2 \leq \int_{a}^{b}\bigg(\int_{a}^{t}|(K(t,s)|^2ds \cdot \int_{a}^{t}|f(s)ds|^2ds\bigg)dt$$

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuuming that $K \in L^{2}([a,b]\times [a,b])$ we have

$$\int_{a}^{b}\bigg(\int_{a}^{t}|(K(t,s)|^2ds \cdot \int_{a}^{t}|f(s)ds|^2ds\bigg)dt$$ $$\leq \int_{a}^{b}\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}|(K(t,s)|^2ds \cdot \int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^2ds\bigg)dt$$

Now just pull out the constant $$\int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^2ds.$$

Comment: Could you please explain why its legal to use the schwarz inequality for the second step? Our upper limit is $t$ not $b$, so it's technically not the $L^2$ inner product that we are considering so how can we use the inequality? (Also, thank you!)

Comment: $\int_a^{t} h(s)ds=\int_a^{b} \phi (s)ds$ where $\phi (s)=h(s)\chi_{(a,t)} (s)$. Note also that $(\chi_{(a,t)} (s))^{2}=\chi_{(a,t)} (s)$ so we can use the factor $\chi_{(a,t)} (s)$ for each of the two functions.  @ali

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $\chi_{(a,t)}(s)$ (which is where maybe my initial confusion arose)

Comment: It is the characteristic function of the interval.